# How to catch IOException's while using Spring WebClient?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-webflux

I'm working on a project in which we are migrating from `RestTemplate` to `WebClient`.

The `WebClient` is implemented like this:

```
try {
    ...
    return webClient
        .get()
        .uri(someUri)
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(SomeBusinessClass.class).block()
} catch(WebClientException e) {
    // do some stuff
    // want to catch IOExceptions here as well
}
```

While refactoring the code I had to refactor the tests as well and I've come across a test in which we basically throw an `ConnectException` to see if our internal code catch them according to our needs. With `RestTemplate`'s exception classes we was able to define the exception like this:

```
ResourceAccessException exc = new ResourceAccessException("I/O error on GET request", new ConnectException("Connection refused: connect"))
```

I tried to do the same with `WebClient`'s provided exception class `WebClientException` but that's an abstract class and the only class inheriting from it is `WebClientResponseException` and that don't provide a constructor which would allow to do the same. So my only option was to do it with `RuntimeException`:

```
RuntimeException exc = new RuntimeException("I/O error on GET request", new ConnectException("Connection refused: connect"))
```

But since I don't want to rewrite our internal code to catch exceptions on `RuntimeException` level but on `WebClientException` level, is that not an option and I'm wondering how to do that?

I tried to find out in the Spring docs how to handle `IOException`'s while using `WebClient` but couldn't find anything.

What would be the approach here?

Comment: show us the code

Comment: @ThomasAndolf is this enough?

Comment: what do you define as I/O exceptions? a restclient does not throw I/O exceptions, a restclient does restcalls and gets status codes back that you assert and take appropriate action on. Why not just read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve and see how they handle status codes.

Comment: For example a ConnectException like you can see in my question. The why is because we catch such exceptions while making our calls. And we already catch the status codes but need to catch IOExceptions as well.

Comment: then post your real code and not a "sort of" code if you expect real help, and not "sort of" help

Comment: Guess I'm not clear enough. My Bad. :) But I just want to know how to handle exceptions e.g. in case of my internet connection broke's up while I'm making a call with the WebClient (like seen above) without catching RuntimeException's. Because before, as we used RestTemplate instead of WebClient, we was able to do that by only catching RestClientException's (where we now have to use WebClientException).

Comment: if your internet connection breaks the webclient will return an exception containing a `503 Service Unavailable` and you will handle it the regular way as you would handle any exception, your custom class `ResourceAccessException` is not en exception, since it is not _thrown_ its just a regular class. So we can\t help you unless we see how you ppl have solved it atm. since your solution doesn't seem to be bast practice. And i can't see the big picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *nicest* way would almost certainly be to handle all errors in the reactive stream itself. Server response errors are usually best handled by using `exchange()` rather than `retrieve()` and then dealing with the response manually, and an underlying `IOException` by using the `onErrorResume()`, `onErrorReturn()` etc. reactive operators available for this purpose.

However, you mention you're migrating from blocking code, so I understand that practically that may not (yet) be on the cards. If you want to stick to catching exceptions:

> But since I don't want to rewrite our internal code to catch exceptions on RuntimeException level but on WebClientException level, is that not an option and I'm wondering how to do that?

Wanting to catch *all* transport errors under the umbrella of `WebClientException` is not a sensible option. As you say, neither is just catching `RuntimeException` for obvious reasons.

Simplifying it, `WebClientException` means "I connected to the URL and sent stuff to it without an issue, but it told me to sod off" (ie. it generated an error code rather than a 200 response.)

That might be because of a 404 (resource not found), 500 (server error), 418 (you're trying to connect to a teapot, not a server), etc.

`IOException` on the other hand means "Couldn't even establish a connection to this URL." That could be because the connection was actively refused, the domain name couldn't be resolved, the SSL cert expired, etc.

The two are not analogous, and it would be rather odd and confusing to treat them that way.

If you want to *handle* them in the same block, then that's fine - naively you might just do:

```
catch(WebClientException|IOException e) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

...but you can't of course, because `IOException` is checked. (Reactive streams in Java don't throw checked exceptions, each checked exception is mapped to a `RuntimeException` instead.)

However, you *can* map all `IOException` to an `UncheckedIOException`:

```
return webClient
    .get()
    .uri(someUri)
    .retrieve()
    .toEntity(SomeBusinessClass.class)
    .onErrorMap(IOException.class, UncheckedIOException::new)
    .block()
```

...and then either do `catch(WebClientException|UncheckedIOException ex)`, or deal with them in separate catch blocks.

This certainly isn't the "nice" way to handle exceptions from a reactive mindset, but if you're aiming to migrate with the fewest possible changes, this is likely what you're after.